# Algorithm for processing the string

Tags: c, string, function, replace

I really don't know how to implement this function:
The function should take a pointer to an integer, a pointer to an array of strings, and a string for processing. The function should write to array all variations of exchange '**ch**' combination to '**@**' symbol and change the integer to the size of this array. Here is an example of processing:

```
choker => {"choker","@oker"}

chocho => {"chocho","@ocho","cho@o","@o@o"}

chachacha => {"chachacha","@achacha","cha@acha","chacha@a","@a@acha","cha@a@a","@acha@a","@a@a@a"}
```

I am writing this in C standard 99. So this is sketch:

```
int n;
char **arr;
char *string = "chacha";
func(&n,&arr,string);
```

And function sketch:

```
int func(int *n,char ***arr, char *string) {

}
```

So I think I need to create another function, which counts the number of 'ch' combinations and allocates memory for this one. I'll be glad to hear any ideas about this algorithm.

Comment: Check out this link http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/767.
You can model your algorithm around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of combinations pretty easily:

```
char * tmp = string;
int i;
for(i = 0; *tmp != '\0'; i++){
    if(!(tmp = strstr(tmp, "ch")))
        break;
    tmp += 2; // Skip past the 2 characters "ch"
}

// i contains the number of times ch appears in the string.

int num_combinations = 1 << i;

// num_combinations contains the number of combinations. Since this is 2 to the power of the number of occurrences of "ch"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd create a helper function, e.g. countChs that would just iterate over the string and return the number of 'ch'-s. That should be easy, as no string overlapping is involved.

When you have the number of occurences, you need to allocate space for **2^count strings**, with each string (apart from the original one) of length **strlen(original) - 1**. You also alter your n variable to be equal to that 2^count.

After you have your space allocated, just iterate over all indices in your new table and fill them with copies of the original string (strcpy() or strncpy() to copy), then replace 'ch' with '@' in them (there are loads of ready snippets online, just look for "C string replace").

Finally make your arr pointer point to the new table. Be careful though - if it pointed to some other data before, you should think about freeing it or you'll end up having memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have all variations of replaced string, array size will have `2^n` elements. Where `n` - number of "ch" substrings. So, calculating this will be:

```
int i = 0;
int n = 0;
while(string[i] != '\0')
{
    if(string[i] == 'c' && string[i + 1] == 'h')
        n++;

    i++;
}
```

Then we can use binary representation of number. Let's note that incrementing integer from `0` to `2^n`, the binary representation of i-th number will tell us, which "ch" occurrence to change. So:

```
for(long long unsigned int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++)
{
    long long unsigned int number = i;
    int k = 0;

    while(number > 0)
    {
        if(number % 2 == 1)
            // Replace k-th occurence of "ch"

        number /= 2;
        k++;
    }

    // Add replaced string to array
}
```

This code check every bit in binary representation of `number` and changes k-th occurrence if k-th bit is 1. Changing k-th "ch" is pretty easy, and I leave it for you.

This code is useful only for 64 or less occurrences, because unsigned `long long int` can hold only `2^64` values.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sub-problems that you need to solve for your original problem:

- allocating space for the array of variations
- calculating the variations

For the first problem, you need to find the mathematical function `f` that takes the number of "ch" occurrences in the input string and returns the number of total variations.
Based on your examples: `f(1) = 1`, `f(2) = 4` and `f(3) = 8`. This should give you a good idea of where to start, but it is important to *prove* that your function is correct. Induction is a good way to make that proof.

Since your replace process ensures that the results have either the same of a lower length than the original you can allocate space for each individual result equal to the length of original.

As for the second problem, the simplest way is to use recursion, like in the example provided by nightlytrails.

You'll need another function which take the array you allocated for the results, a `count` of results, the current state of the string and an `index` in the current string.

When called, if there are no further occurrences of "ch" beyond the `index` then you save the result in the array at position `count` and increment `count` (so the next time you don't overwrite the previous result).

If there are any "ch" beyond `index` then call this function twice (the recurrence part). One of the calls uses a copy of the current string and only increments the `index` to just beyond the "ch". The other call uses a copy of the current string with the "ch" replaced by "@" and increments the `index` to beyond the "@".

Make sure there are no memory leaks. No `malloc` without a matching `free`.
After you make this solution work you might notice that it plays loose with memory. It is using more than it should. Improving the algorithm is an exercise for the reader.